# Fancybox Button Problems

Tags: jquery, button, fancybox

How do I put prev and next buttons under an iframe window with fancy box.

I've written this:

```
jQuery("#yayla").fancybox({
    'overlayShow'       : true,
    'overlayColor'      : '#dfdfdf',
    'overlayOpacity'    : 0.9,
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none',
    'type'              : 'iframe',
    'width'             : '50%',
    'height'            : '75%',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a gallery of images for instance and integrate the `iframe` to that gallery so assuming you have for your pictures:

```
$('.fancyImage').fancybox();

<a rel="gallery" class="fancyImage" href="image01.jpg"...
<a rel="gallery" class="fancyImage" href="image02.jpg"...
<a rel="gallery" class="fancyImage" href="image03.jpg"...
```

with the same script above for the `iframe`, you can add it to gallery just setting the same `rel` attribute to anchor like:

```
<a rel="gallery" id="yayla" href="samplePage.html" ....
```

Comment: But it should be also iframe windows. I tried to do this before, If I using as gallery then page closing when I doubt click to on window.

Comment: be sure you set hideOnContentClick to false

Comment: If you think I gave the right answer, please don't forget to mark this as correct. Thanks.